# Update Live Tile with latest news from RSS feed

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

So I want to add a Iconic live tile to my app to display the latest RSS news to its Iconic tile.

Noob here. Anyone can tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have now code which gather RSS news and store it somewhere.
After that you just can use code from [here (Nokia Dev Center)](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Live_Tile_Templates_in_Windows_Phone_8#Iconic_Tile_Template) - there is nice example.

Just create object and set some properties:

```
IconicTileData oIcontile = new IconicTileData(); // Create icon tile
// Now you can set some properties
oIcontile.Title = "Tile title";
oIcontile.Count = 7; // Some counter
```

If you don't have code for RSS - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487167%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is tutorial from MSDN site.

Comment: So you store it somewhere - you can access it and just put on a tile. :-) I don't know how it is done in your code.